# Unidentified Property in Control in my codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to frameworks and trying to send values to database table, I have done it simply but now I am using templates (the famous alemsaeed free AdminLTE) now after setting BASEPATH and giving database connection in database.php,I am still getting errors.

However the code looks fine but I don't know please kindly tell me the reason it's my 2nd week in codeigniter.

**MODEL**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Mdl extends CI_Model {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
 }
 function form_insert($data){
     $data = array(

        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
        'dob' =>$this->input->post('dob')
    );
    $this->db->insert('folio', $data);
   }
   }
   ?>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function index() {

 $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
 $this->load->view('myself');
  }
 public function eid() {
 $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
 $this->load->database();
$this->load->model('mdl');
 $this->model->form_insert();
$this->load->view('edu');
 }
 }
 ?>
```

**View**

> Note:i have shorted the whole view code because it's a template 
>   
>   For Form Loading the usual

```
       <?php
         echo form_open(site_url().'/ctrl/eid/');
         $attributes = array('class' => 'sidebar-form');
         ?>
```

```
                <label>Enter Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="YourName" name="name">
                <label>Father Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="father name">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer">
                Copyright &copy; 2015-2016 <a     href="http://almsaeedstudio.com"> PIET MULTAN</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the property name?? What is the Error message??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem was in the Controller**
it should be the modelfileName not model in the code where we load the function

```
$this->mdl->form_insert();
```

And this did work :D

**The Next problem was in the sitemap**

it was this before

```
    $config['site_url']='../../folio/';
```

instead of this

```
   $config['site_url']='http://localhost/folio/index.php/';
```

But Once Again i appreciate all for your help it really means to me a lot .

## THK_STACOVRFLW

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove argument $data from form_insert method of model. Like: `public function form_insert() {/* rest of code here */}` because you are not passing anything from controller. Although I would advice you that you do that passing from controller like:

```
public function eid()
{
    //controller
    $data = array();

    $data['name'] => $this->input->post('name'),
    $data['fname'] => $this->input->post('fname'),
    $data['dob'] =>$this->input->post('dob'),


    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('mdl');
    if ( $this->model->form_insert($data) )
    {
        //success view
    }
    else
    {
        //insert fail view
    }
}

function form_insert($data)
{
    //model
    $this->db->insert('folio', $data);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Controller

```
    function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();

      //load default helpers in this

      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->helper('url');
      $this->load->model('mdl');
    }

    public function index()
    {
      $this->load->view('myself');
    }

    public function eid()
    {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $dob = $_POST['dob'];

      if(!empty($name) || !empty($fname) || !empty($dob))
      {
          $this->Mdl->form_insert($name, $fname, $dob);//Model name should be Mdl
          $this->load->view('edu');
      }
      else
      {
        //fields are empty
      }


    }
```

In Model

```
  function form_insert($name, $fname, $dob)
  {
      $data = array(
          'name' => $name,
          'fname' => $fname,
          'dob' => $dob
      );
      $this->db->insert('folio', $data);
  }
```

In View (Form should be)

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ctrl/eid" method="post" class="sidebar-form">
        <label>Enter Your Name</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="YourName" name="name">
        <label>Father Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="father name">
        <label>Date Of Birth</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Submit</button>
    </form>
```